# Let some routes access on IP blocked Apache server

Tags: .htaccess, symfony, apache2.4

I have an apache 2.4 server, hosting a Symfony website. Server is accessible only from some IPs via .htaccess:

```
<RequireAny>
    Require all denied
    Require ip x.xx.xxx.xx
</RequireAny>
```

That is working fine. Problem is that now I want to let requests access from any IP to some routes only. For example /login. I "know" that in Symfony, internally, the route is like app.php/login but I tried these unsuccessfully:

```
Require expr %{REQUEST_URI} = "/app_dev\.php/login"
Require expr %{REQUEST_URI} = "/app\.php/login"
Require expr %{REQUEST_URI} = "/login"
Require expr %{REQUEST_URI} = "login"
```

if I create a login.php file, this works fine, but of course I can't do that for all routes:

```
Require expr %{REQUEST_URI} = "/login\.php"
```

The error is always the same:

```
"GET /login HTTP/1.1" 403
```

Comment: What are the public route of your Symfony's application ? Why don't you use the `app/config/security.yml` access_control part to handle the route restrictions ? Please take a look at the [documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/access_control.html)

Comment: Actually I'm using that for other things, but I wanted to block requests at server level, to avoid bugs or security issues. If I don't find a better solution, I will use this.